# Matching letters to word(Unity3D)

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, char, matching

I wrote a method in unity but I think it is wrong. I want to do if some sorted letters matching to any word, then it will say true.

I mean 10 columns and 20 rows char array. the method will check the letters up to down or left to right(like scrabble game).

e.g. there is a word in char array "H","U","N","D". this letters will match and matched letters will destroy in game and it will be null in char array. I wrote this code at below but does not work. where do i wrong?

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ColumnLetters
{
  public string[] lettersRows = new string[20];
}

public ColumnLetters[] lettersColumns = new ColumnLetters[10];

public void CheckWord()
{
    foreach (string item in answers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersColumns.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < lettersColumns[i].lettersRows.Length; j++)
            {
                if (item == lettersColumns[i].lettersRows[j])
                {
                    Debug.Log("True");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("false");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is incomplete. Let's say your game matrix looks like this:

> A B C D E
>
> F H U N D
>
> G H I J K

And:

> item = "HUND";

When you do this:

> if (item == lettersColumns[i].lettersRows[j])

you're just checking if a single letter in the game matrix is equal to "HUND".

So, in this case:

> lettersColumns[0].lettersRows[0] == "A"
>
> lettersColumns[2].lettersRows[1] == "U"

So, the check you're doing here is this:

> if ("HUND" == "A") Debug.Log("True");
>
> if ("HUND" == "B") Debug.Log("True");
>
> ...
>
> if ("HUND" == "H") Debug.Log("True");
>
> if ("HUND" == "U") Debug.Log("True");
>
> if ("HUND" == "N") Debug.Log("True");
>
> if ("HUND" == "D") Debug.Log("True");
>
> ...

And none of these is ever true. What you can do is first find the position of letter "H" in the matrix. Then look at the position left of "H" and check if there's a letter "U" there. If there's no letter "U" there, try finding "U" right of "H". If you did find "U" left of "H", check the position left of "U" for letter "N" etc. Do this for all four directions. Then do all this for the next letter "H" in the matrix.

I strongly suggest reading more about iterating over arrays and matrices to help you with this solution. Once you write your solution with this approach, search for "crossword/scrabble algorithms" for a faster solution using search trees.

Comment: I wrote this but its writing reverse, I mean down to up for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            rows[i] = "";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersColumns.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (string item in lettersColumns[i].lettersRows)
            {
                rows[i] += item;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (item.Contains("AB"))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("True");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simple.

- You can have a List of all the words the board can have.
- Then, in each letter selection you check if the `list.Contains(currentSelection)`

**Example**

I select the H, so i do currentSelection += H

Then i check `list.Contains(currentSelection)` ? if so, destroy

else

I select next letter U, and so on.

Comment: my game is a word game of tetris. tetrominos has letters, they will down as horizontal or vertical. sure any letters contains a word, then it will score. I did rows and columns for it. placed tetrominos writing to rows or columns array but I could not do spacing. I wrote contains and null but failed.